# Variable config not found in MY_Controller Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got error when I run this code

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function MY_Controller () {
        var_dump ( $this->config->item ('default_app') );
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Message: Undefined property: Welcome::$config
```

My MY_Controller is in Core folder & I use Codeigniter 3.0.6. The error tells that variable $config is not found.

Comment: How do you run that code? It seems you have a Welcome controller, right?

Comment: In what config file is 'default_app' defined and where do you load that config file?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function MY_Controller()
    {
        var_dump ( $this->config->item('default_app') );
    }
}
```

with

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        var_dump ( $this->config->item('default_app') );
    }
}
```